# Call "private" method from "parent" object in javascript

Tags: javascript

in the following code, i need call the "private" method `run` in the sub class `Worker`

```
function Person(scope, ...) {
  scope.name = "Juan";

  var run = function() {
     console.log(scope.name + " is running");
  };
}

function Worker(scope, ...) {
  Person.call(this, scope, ...);

  var jumpAndRun = function() {
     console.log(scope.name + " is jumping");
     run(); // how to call this
  };
}

Worker.prototype = Object.create(People.prototype);
```

currently if i call `run` method i get an `Error: run is not defined!`

Comment: That's outright impossible. It's totally private to the `People` constructor function scope, not somehow "protected".

Comment: Why can't you make it public? From where are `run` and `jumpAndRun` invoked anyway?

Comment: My recommendation: Don't try to simulate something that the language does not support. Keep it simple. It makes the code: easier to understand and easier to maintain.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah you are right but i wont rewrite many code is the same in many places, currently i'm refactoring

Comment: Also, what the heck is `scope`?

Comment: @JoeFrambach scope, and other arguments are injected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, can't do it, unless the `People` class (which should be called `Person`) makes that method available.

A common practice is to make "private" methods start with an underscore. It does not 100% grant any security, but it at least gives other developers a hint that it is meant to be private.

```
function Person(scope, ...) {
  scope.name = "Juan";

  var run = function() {
     console.log(scope.name + " is running");
  };

  this._run = run;
}

function Worker(scope, ...) {
  Person.call(this, scope, ...);

  var jumpAndRun = function() {
     console.log(scope.name + " is jumping");
     this._run(); // how to call this
  };
}
```

Comment: Your `jumpAndRun` function would need to be a method as well, though.

Comment: @rkmax have you added the this._run = run; in the Person costructor?

Comment: Here I've done what I think is right, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLqb1tyo/